# pygame not rendering a sprite group

Tags: python, pygame

I'm remaking snake in python using pygame, and I have two sprite groups, `snake_group` and `apple_group`, they are both mostly the same, but when drawing apple_group, it doesn't appear in the window.

numbers greater than 0 on the board is the snake, and the apple is -1.

there's no code for the snake to move, and there's a lot of code that isn't used yet.

here's my code:

```
import random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snakeBoard = [
    [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]

boardWidth = 20
boardHeight = 20

move = 0
direction = 1

background_color = (0,0,0)
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('this is a game')
screen.fill(background_color)


class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,width,height,x,y,color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x+300,y+300]

class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([30,30])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x+300,y+300]

snake_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
apple_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_UP) and not (direction == 2):
                direction = 1
            if (event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN) and not (direction == 1):
                direction = 2
            if (event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT) and not (direction == 4):
                direction = 3
            if (event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT) and not (direction == 3):
                direction = 4
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(background_color)
    snake_group.empty()
    apple_group.empty()

    iterate1 = 0
    iterate2 = 0
    boardX = 0
    boardY = 0

    while iterate1 < boardHeight:
        while iterate2 < boardWidth:
            if snakeBoard[iterate1][iterate2] > 0:
                snake = Snake(30,30,boardX,boardY,(255,255,255))
                snake_group.add(snake)
            if snakeBoard[iterate1][iterate2] == -1:
                apple = Apple(boardX,boardY,(255,0,0))
                apple_group.add(apple)
            boardX += 30
            iterate2 += 1
        boardX = 0
        boardY -= 30
        iterate2 = 0
        iterate1 += 1

    snake_group.draw(screen)
    apple_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Apple` and `Snake` classes you have set their rectangles to the screen's rectangle

```py
self.rect = screen.get_rect()
```

Why are you setting your sprites' rectangles to have the same dimensions as the screen? This is causing the apple to go out of the screen. You can replace this line with

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

to get a rectangle of the same dimensions as your `self.image` and the apple is visible.